# How to handle `null` strings coming from a RESTful API in JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json

Here's a service return, that gives us user's profile info:

```
{
   email: 'someone@example.com',
   pictureUrl: 'http://example.com/profile-pictures/somebody.png',
   phone: null,
   name: null
}
```

Now we get this JSON in our android app, and turn it into `JSONObject` model:

```
JSONObject profileInfo = new JSONObject(profileInfoJson);
```

And we bind UI views to data:

```
email.setText(profileInfo.getString("email"));
phone.setText(profileInfo.getString("phone"));
name.setText(profileInfo.getString("name"));
```

Then in our `TextView` or `EditView` we have `null` string, instead of having nothing.

It's possible that we check `null` values using if-then statements, but that's too much for a real-world application with so many fields.

Is there a way to configure `JSONObject` to gracefully handle `null` strings?

**Update**: I used `optString` with a fallback, as suggested, but it has no effect:

```
firstName.setText(profileInfo.optString("firstName", ""));
```

And the result is the same `EditText` has `null` in it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`optString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), if no suitable value is found then the second parameter will be returned instead of exception or `null`

```
phone.setText(profileInfo.optString("phone","nophone"));
name.setText(profileInfo.optString("name","noname"));
```

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists, coercing(try to cast) it if
>   necessary, or fallback(return second parameter)if no such mapping exists.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood me. The point is, the parameter exists. It only has `null` as a valid JSON value, but when it's converted to `JSONObject` that `null` becomes a string. I used your suggestion and it didn't work.

Comment: a small hack, you can do something like , `name.setText(profileInfo.optString("name").replace("null","No name found"));`